# Merge and sum items with the same id

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Using Laravel and PHP I have to merge an items with same product_id to know how many of them i have i  warehouse. I'm grabbing all products in current warehouse and I get.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "factor" => -1
    "quantity" => 14
    "product_name" => "Phone"
    "product_id" => 1
    "product_symbol" => "iP"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "factor" => 1
    "quantity" => 120
    "product_name" => "Phone"
    "product_id" => 1
    "product_symbol" => "iP"

  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "factor" => -1
    "quantity" => 5
    "product_name" => "Sam Washing Machinge"
    "product_id" => 2
    "product_symbol" => "Sa_DA123WE"

  ]
]
```

Now In my View I want to display current inventory status:

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach($values as $key => $value)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{$value->product_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$value->product_symbol}}</td>
                            <td>{{$value->quantity}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

The problem is this is diaplsying like:

```
Name: Symbol: Quantity:
Phone iP          14
Phone iP          120
Sam   Sa           5
```

So as You see i have two entries with Phone and there has to be only one, because it's the same item it has to be calculated like:

```
(foreach products with the same id factorOfTheFirstItem*quantityOfTheFirstItem + factorOfTheSecondItem*quantityOfTheSecondItem and so).
```

So the finally my site has to look:

```
Name: Symbol: Quantity:
Phone iP          106
Sam   Sa           5
```

Controller:

```
$values= Document::where('id_warehouse', $warehouseId)
            ->leftJoin('document_items', 'documents.id', '=','document_items.document_id')
            ->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'document_items.product_id')
            ->select('documents.factor as factor', 'document_items.quantity as quantity','products.name as product_name','products.id as product_id','products.symbol as product_symbol')

    ->get()->toArray();
return view('admin.inventory.index', compact('values'));
```

Thak you for help! :)

Comment: You can simply get SUM from mysql using Group by. It will be faster and efficient, because then data packet being transferred from DB to Application would be smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you desire in the end (the following):

```
Name: Symbol: Quantity:
Phone iP          106
Sam   Sa           5
```

You can improve your query and obtain this results fairly easy, something like this should work:

```
$documents = Document::where('id_warehouse', $warehouseId)
        ->leftJoin('document_items', 'documents.id', '=','document_items.document_id')
        ->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'document_items.product_id')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('SUM(document_items.quantity) as quantity'),
            'products.name as product_name',
            'products.id as product_id',
            'products.symbol as product_symbol'
          )
         ->groupBy('products.name', 'products.id', 'products.symbol')
         ->get();
```

With this, you should get an array with the same properties you want.

Comment: I don't think this answer satisfies the requirements, since he wants to sum up 'quantity' while considering the 'factor'.

Comment: Just did `DB::raw('SUM(document_items.quantity * documents.factor) as quantity'),`

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `toArray()` function. because its way too easier to handle `Collections`. so,

```
$documents = Document::whateverYourQuery()->get();

// final collection which will hold 'merged data'
$merged_documents = collect();

foreach($documents as $document) {

    // set a new attribute with 'factoredquantity'
    $document->setAttribute('factored_quantity', $document->factor . $document->quantity);

    // set a new attribute with sum of the 'factored quantity' (which is what you need)
    $document->setAttribute('total_quantity', $documents->sum->factored_quantity);

    // set updated 'document' object to the final collection.
    // put function will eliminate duplicates.
    $merged_documents->put($document->id, $document);

}
```

now in your every document object has a total Quantity attribute, which you can access as `$document->total_quantity`

finally you can call `toArray()` function on 'merged_data' collection, if you want.